# Ceiling fan install

Tags: ceiling-fan

On a new house pre wired for ceiling fan. Installing a new fan with remote control. I have an extra wire red in color. Should that be connected to the black also

Comment: What make and model is the fan? Is there one wall switch or two present?

Comment: Is the "extra wire red in color" the house wiring or the wiring of the fan?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. We'll need more information before we can help you with this.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to use remote control you do not need the red wire.  Just cap it off and push back into box.